# codeigniter DB Connect issue

Tags: codeigniter

I have transferred my CI 2.0 site from one domain to updated PHP version new domain.

But I am getting one problem to connect database or something else, don't know exactly.

> object(CI_DB_mysqli_result)#24 (7) { ["conn_id"]=> bool(false)
>   ["result_id"]=> NULL ["result_array"]=> array(0) { }
>   ["result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["current_row"]=> int(0)
>   ["num_rows"]=> NULL ["row_data"]=> NULL }

I am getting this as result when I am calling any query of select etc.

Can anyone help me out what is wrong in it?

Comment: show your   db configuration and also select query

Comment: $db['default'] = array(
 'dsn' => '',
 'hostname' => 'xxxxxx',
 'username' => 'xxxxx',
 'password' => 'xxxxx',
 'database' => 'purchaser',
 'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
 'dbprefix' => '',
 'pconnect' => TRUE,
 'db_debug' => TRUE,
 'cache_on' => FALSE,
 'cachedir' => '',
 'char_set' => 'utf8',
 'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
 'swap_pre' => '',
 'encrypt' => FALSE,
 'compress' => FALSE,
 'stricton' => FALSE,
 'failover' => array(),
 'save_queries' => TRUE
);

Comment: $query = $this->db->select($this->identity_column.', id, password, group_id')
         ->where($this->identity_column, $identity)
         ->where('active', 1)
         ->where($this->ion_auth->_extra_where)
         ->limit(1)
         ->get($this->tables['users']);

Comment: working on localhost or live server

Comment: https://www.onni.com/purchaser/login

live server..this one.

Comment: so basically when we will get this? - ["conn_id"]=> bool(false)

Comment: try with replace  'pconnect' => TRUE to  'pconnect' => FALSE

Comment: tried that.. but same problem.. In fact I tried every possible way.  but no result :(

Comment: 'dbdriver' => 'mysqli' instead of this use 'dbdriver' => 'mysql' for CI2 and try